# Postgresql : return string that contains one or more of specified special characters

Tags: postgresql

**special character list - ?<!>*^**

REGEX
it checks patterns -> in same order. In postgres no regex, instead used ~.

LIKE also can do pattern matching but with wildcard.

SIMILAR TO returns true and false.

SUBSTRING returns only the matched string.

In our case, any of the chars in the list if present gets matched.
So maybe we can use OR operator like

```
select gid, title, description from public.logical WHERE gid like '%?%'
or gid like '%<%'
or gid like '%!%'
or gid like '%>%'
or gid like '%*%'
or gid like '%^%';
```

I am trying to get a better technique than this.

Answer (score 0):

Regex doesn't check the "order" of the characters if you use a character range `[...]`

```
with logical (gid) as (
  values ('foo'), ('foo-bar'), ('^bar'), ('Foo!'), ('foo ><'), ('bar -')
)
select *
from logical
where gid ~ '[- ?<!>*^]'
```

The above returns all values except `'foo'`